# How does Critical Ascension work?

Tags: borderlands-2

The Assassin/Zero's Critical Ascensi0n skill stacks bonuses from Sniper Critical Hits. The stacks slowly decay, but over how much time? How can I check how many stacks I have? How can I tell if it's active at all? Does scoring a new Crit Hit preserve the whole stack for longer, or just the latest stacks? How can I prolong the stacks' effects?

[image: Critical Ascensi0n]

Comment: Am I the only one who cringed at their misuse of "awhile" there? P.S. the skill sounds awesome, 999 stacks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[User Zikel, in the /r/Borderlands subreddit has tested Critical Ascension](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/15op84/many_skill_descriptions_are_misleading_dont_tell/) and came up with the ff. results:

> You start losing stacks after **6 seconds**.
>
> You lose **1 stack per second**.
>
> Switching weapon, opening a menu (map, inventory, quest log, etc),
>   using a vending machine, talking to a quest giver and dying instantly
>   removes all stacks.
>
> You can melee, throw grenades and sprint without losing all stacks!

---

<sup>Source: [Reddit /r/Borderlands post by user Zikel, "*Many skill descriptions are misleading, don't tell the full story or straight up lie to you. I took it upon my self to test EVERYTHING and clear up the confusion. Here are the results.*"](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/15op84/many_skill_descriptions_are_misleading_dont_tell/)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

They *start* to decay in 6 seconds.  After about 12 seconds, they decay *rapidly*.  You lose about 70 stacks in about 10 seconds or less.  This limits the utility of the skill greatly.

Answer (score 5):

This ability has [spawned a discussion](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?p=2774186) over at the GearBox forums, apparently this buff stacks caused by this ability currently last for 'approximately' six seconds before it begins to decay.

The general opinion for this seems to be that if the stack lasted longer, the ability in general would be overpowered.

Comment: 999 critical hits with less than 6 seconds between them? Good luck

Comment: @BenBrocka I think they mean that if you haven't scored a crit in 6 seconds then the stacks are removed.

Comment: If you don't critical hit within a six second period the stacks begin to decay (ie: drop off one at a time) is the way I understood it

Comment: Oh, yeah, one stack per 6 seconds makes sense given *slowly* decay

Comment: Has anyone got this to verify? Considering how many enemies there are in some areas you could easily keep this going for a while. And would you really end up with 999*6% critical and 999*5% damage? :O